# Python requests web data

Tags: python, json

hi all i have the following code which is working just fine

```
import requests

import json

f= open
r=requests.get('https://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/54c234f02ec4abe957b84f37?format=json')

data = r.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:

json.dump(data, f)
```

but i wish to make the toilet id part of the url, above it's 54c234f02ec4abe957b84f37?, dynamic. it must read from a json list, i can load the list via this code  -

```
import json

with open('loos.json') as json_data:


d = json.load(json_data)
```

but i cannot figure out how to make the 'id' read from the loos dataset, appending each json result to the json dump, as it iterates through the 'loos' dataset

i feel i'm so close to completing this task but just need a tip or 2

many thanks.

***Appended Update***

```
`import json
import requests

with open('Tloos.json') as json_data:

data = json.load(json_data)

for i, loo in enumerate(data['features']):
    loo_id = loo['_id']
    r=requests.get('https://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/{}?format=json'.format(loo_id))

data = r.json()
with open('data%d.json' %i, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)`
```

So, that's my attempt but it's only saving the last loo id in the outputted json file, i guess it's overwriting the others (my test Tloos.json file has 3 loos in total) or not iterating properly? how do i go about debugging this?

Comment: Something like the following might help: `'https://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/{}?format=json'.format(loo.id)`

Comment: thanks so much for the tip, i had something similar earlier but just couldn't quite nail it - in terms of making it run through the entirety of  the 'loos' dataset before dumping out to a json file

Answer (score 1):

What you specified can be done very easily using the string `format` function.

```
import requests
import json

with open('loos.json') as json_data:
    loo_id = json.load(json_data)['id']

r=requests.get('https://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/{}?format=json'.format(loo_id))

data = r.json()
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

This'll give you the gist of how to do it. I don't know your loos.json structure for sure, so you'll have to tweak it as you need to get the `loo_id`. The rest remains the same.

If you want to iterate over many loo_ids, you'd have to do something like this with a loop:

```
for i, loo in enumerate(loo_structure['features']):
    loo_id = loo['_id']
    r=requests.get('https://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/{}?format=json'.format(loo_id))

    data = r.json()
    with open('data%d.json' %i, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Where `loo_ids` is some iterable containing your ids.

Comment: again, thanks for this, i shall implement the advice and re-write my script

Comment: @Dan Sure. If it works, do consider marking my answer and closing your question. Cheers.

Comment: here is the 'loos' structure, if it helps - {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"_id":"54c2346a2ec4abe957b8353a"},{"_id":"54c2346a2ec4abe957b8353b"}

Comment: @Dan Updated my second code listing. Hopefully this is enough for you to develop a solid app. :)

Comment: nearly cracked it, just a small issue - see appended comments

Comment: @Dan You need to change the value of i every time you dump the json, otherwise you dump to the same file.

Comment: So, the current state is that the dump is overwriting? I have 12000 IDs to iterate over so need them all to append to 1 json output - sorry for the novice question, i like to have a clear view of what's happening.

Comment: @Dan From your earlier comments I was given to believe you wanted each json in a separate file. Now I think I've understood a bit better. In each iteration you'll need to accumulate your data in a data structure and then dump it once at the end.